# Custom scrollbar not working in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbars

I am trying to add a custom scrollbar to my div. I've tried many of them, this is the current one that I'm using, but none of them work in the div I want.
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

So, first:
I need that scrollbar to work in the #sidebar-friends div, since that's where the data is being appended to. When I put it to #sidebar-wrapper it works properly. 
Basically, this is my HTML part:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
<div id="sidebar-right">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;" id="activatesidebar" data-name="show"><img style="vertical-align: middle" id="sidebar-icon" src="/templates/v1/assets/img/users-sidebar.png"></a>
<span id="friendsloadertxt" style="display: none; margin-right: 5px">Loading friend list..</span>
<i style="display: none;" id="friendsloader" class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>
<hr id="sidebar-spacer" style="display: none; opacity:0.7">
<div id="sidebar-friends">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar-friends {
position: relative;
}

#sidebar-wrapper{
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 19%; 
max-height: 350px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar-right {
position: relative;
width: 78px;
float:right;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
color:white;
border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
margin-right:-10px;
transition: width 1.5s;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

The javascript part:

```
$("#sidebar-friends").mCustomScrollbar({
axis: 'y',
theme: 'minimal',
mouseWheel: {
enable: true
},
scrollbarPosition: 'inside'
});
```

Can someone help me with this please ?

Comment: What exactly about the custom scrollbar isn't working? Is it not showing? Is it not clickable?

Comment: Not showing, even though when I go to Inspect Element on the browser i can see scrollbar's classes have attached themself to the div. Just not showing on #sidebar-friends or any other child div of #sidebar-wrapper

Comment: Try to make a jsfiddle

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2cfb3b6f084f05ab8bc8039aee3ba808 (#sidebar-wrapper)  https://gyazo.com/5c49e0b79477c6294f70e9e560f14be5 (#sidebar-friends). And I've tried making jsfiddle but for some reason jQuery isn't loading

Comment: Is anyone able to help ? :(